# All Forms Not Passing Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

All of the forms in my rails application are not submitting parameters even to the production.log:

```
Started GET "/countries/afghanistan/edit/" for 41.132.43.55 at Tue Sep 27 03:39:06 -0700 2011
  Processing by CountriesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"afghanistan"}
Rendered countries/_form.html.erb (80.2ms)
Rendered application/_nav.html.erb (2.8ms)
Rendered countries/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (85.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 87ms (Views: 85.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started GET "/countries/afghanistan/" for 41.132.43.55 at Tue Sep 27 03:40:20 -0700 2011
  Processing by CountriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"afghanistan"}
Rendered application/_nav.html.erb (3.9ms)
Rendered countries/show.html.erb within layouts/application (16.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 15.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

That's from the edit action and then submitting the form it goes straight to the show action. In my dev inspector it shows that the POST request has been permanently moved (301) to the GET request:

[image]

I'm not sure what too look for at this point. Everything works fine in development but not in production. Here's my production.rb

```
App::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => "***@***.com",
    :password             => "***",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
    :email_prefix => "[Exception] ",
    :sender_address => %{"Exception Notifier" <***@***.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{***@***.com}
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**
Here's the sessions#new

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :login, "Email Address" %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :login, params[:login] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </p>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Log in" %></p>
<% end %>
```

And here's another one of the forms:

```
<%= form_for @satellite do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <% for country in Country.find(:all) %>
      <%= check_box_tag "satellite[country_ids][]", country.id, @satellite.countries.include?(country) %>
      <%= label_tag "satellite[country_ids][]", country.name, :for => "satellite[country_ids][]" %><br />
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

But like I said none of the forms are passing parameters.

**Update 2**
Here's the routes:

```
  edit_current_user        /user/edit(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
             signup        /signup(.:format)                                {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
             logout        /logout(.:format)                                {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
              login        /login(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
           sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)                              {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /sessions(.:format)                              {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}
        new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                          {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
       edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"edit"}
            session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
              users GET    /users(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /users(.:format)                                 {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
           new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
          edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
               user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                             {:controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy"}
               maps GET    /maps(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"maps", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /maps(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"maps", :action=>"create"}
            new_map GET    /maps/new(.:format)                              {:controller=>"maps", :action=>"new"}
           edit_map GET    /maps/:id/edit(.:format)                         {:controller=>"maps", :action=>"edit"}
                map GET    /maps/:id(.:format)                              {:controller=>"maps", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /maps/:id(.:format)                              {:controller=>"maps", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /maps/:id(.:format)                              {:controller=>"maps", :action=>"destroy"}
   country_channels GET    /countries/:country_id/channels(.:format)        {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"index"}
    country_channel GET    /countries/:country_id/channels/:id(.:format)    {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"show"}
 country_satellites GET    /countries/:country_id/satellites(.:format)      {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"index"}
  country_satellite GET    /countries/:country_id/satellites/:id(.:format)  {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"show"}
country_testimonies GET    /countries/:country_id/testimonies(.:format)     {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"index"}
  country_testimony GET    /countries/:country_id/testimonies/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"show"}
 country_statistics GET    /countries/:country_id/statistics(.:format)      {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"index"}
  country_statistic GET    /countries/:country_id/statistics/:id(.:format)  {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"show"}
     country_videos GET    /countries/:country_id/videos(.:format)          {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"index"}
      country_video GET    /countries/:country_id/videos/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"show"}
 country_challenges GET    /countries/:country_id/challenges(.:format)      {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"index"}
  country_challenge GET    /countries/:country_id/challenges/:id(.:format)  {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"show"}
          countries GET    /countries(.:format)                             {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /countries(.:format)                             {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"create"}
        new_country GET    /countries/new(.:format)                         {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"new"}
       edit_country GET    /countries/:id/edit(.:format)                    {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"edit"}
            country GET    /countries/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /countries/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /countries/:id(.:format)                         {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"destroy"}
           channels GET    /channels(.:format)                              {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /channels(.:format)                              {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"create"}
        new_channel GET    /channels/new(.:format)                          {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"new"}
       edit_channel GET    /channels/:id/edit(.:format)                     {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"edit"}
            channel GET    /channels/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /channels/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /channels/:id(.:format)                          {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"destroy"}
         satellites GET    /satellites(.:format)                            {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /satellites(.:format)                            {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"create"}
      new_satellite GET    /satellites/new(.:format)                        {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"new"}
     edit_satellite GET    /satellites/:id/edit(.:format)                   {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"edit"}
          satellite GET    /satellites/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /satellites/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /satellites/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"destroy"}
        testimonies GET    /testimonies(.:format)                           {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /testimonies(.:format)                           {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"create"}
      new_testimony GET    /testimonies/new(.:format)                       {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"new"}
     edit_testimony GET    /testimonies/:id/edit(.:format)                  {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"edit"}
          testimony GET    /testimonies/:id(.:format)                       {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /testimonies/:id(.:format)                       {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /testimonies/:id(.:format)                       {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"destroy"}
         statistics GET    /statistics(.:format)                            {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /statistics(.:format)                            {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"create"}
      new_statistic GET    /statistics/new(.:format)                        {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"new"}
     edit_statistic GET    /statistics/:id/edit(.:format)                   {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"edit"}
          statistic GET    /statistics/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /statistics/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /statistics/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"destroy"}
             videos GET    /videos(.:format)                                {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /videos(.:format)                                {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"create"}
          new_video GET    /videos/new(.:format)                            {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"new"}
         edit_video GET    /videos/:id/edit(.:format)                       {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"edit"}
              video GET    /videos/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /videos/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /videos/:id(.:format)                            {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"destroy"}
         challenges GET    /challenges(.:format)                            {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /challenges(.:format)                            {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"create"}
      new_challenge GET    /challenges/new(.:format)                        {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"new"}
     edit_challenge GET    /challenges/:id/edit(.:format)                   {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"edit"}
          challenge GET    /challenges/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /challenges/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /challenges/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"destroy"}
       all_channels        /all/channels(.:format)                          {:controller=>"channels", :action=>"all"}
     all_satellites        /all/satellites(.:format)                        {:controller=>"satellites", :action=>"all"}
    all_testimonies        /all/testimonies(.:format)                       {:controller=>"testimonies", :action=>"all"}
     all_statistics        /all/statistics(.:format)                        {:controller=>"statistics", :action=>"all"}
         all_videos        /all/videos(.:format)                            {:controller=>"videos", :action=>"all"}
     all_challenges        /all/challenges(.:format)                        {:controller=>"challenges", :action=>"all"}
               root        /(.:format)                                      {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"map"}
               home        /home(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"countries", :action=>"map"}
```

Comment: could you post your view code / html.erb / haml? i guess you're mixing up resourceful routes or http method, are you using plain old `form_for` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting 301's on the form submit, can you post the logs of the actual `POST` from your form rather than the `GET` on edit/show?  Also, could you post the `routes.rb` sections relevant to the forms above?  Could it be a `before_filter` on the controller?

Comment: That log there is what happens when I post a form. It's like it skips the POST request all together. In development it works just fine though. It's very strange.

Comment: Do you have any `before_filter`s ?

Comment: Just ```before_filter :login_required``` for nifty:authentication

Comment: I removed ```before_filter :login_required``` and still had the same problem.

Comment: Hmmm.  Doesn't appear to be a problem with the routes.  I'd imagine you checked both your `ApplicationController` and `SatelitesController` for before_filters?  I don't think it's this, but are you using `protect_from_forgery!`? If so, can you make sure the `authenticity_token` is being submitted with the form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3829/discussion-between-marc-and-kristian-pd)

Comment: The authenticity_token is in the html form ```<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="rBUmo3QH312i/73aUMV6Qg0n1Sopiw0xv2lbfUUP3do=" /></div> 
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing, i ran into a while ago with non-numerical ids, were default constraints on `resources` routes. overriding this constraints solved the issue for, but this should be a problem in development mode as well. anyway, you can try

```
resources :countries, :constraints => { :id => /.*/ }
```

plus your nested routes

Comment: Thanks. Except that no forms across the enter app are passing parameters. It's skipping the POST request all together. Even for the login/signup forms. And everything works fine in development anyways. And the gem 'friendly_id' takes care of this issue for me already.

Comment: ok, last idea: could you show your middleware stack, for development and production? `rake middleware RAILS_ENV=development` and `rake middleware RAILS_ENV=production`